# store onclick url in mysql table and fetch on php page

Tags: php, mysql, database

Working on this [site](http://www.aticolabexport.com/product/digital-universal-testing-machine.php) .Want to store onclick selection of urls and other information while surfing to store in mysql db and fetch the same on user profile page

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: share your tried code ??

Comment: check source code

Comment: no, post the related code here, we will not look at the source and try to find which part is related to your problem

Comment: On product page <?php session_start();
require('../db.php');
$trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "INSERT into `usersdata` (username, productname, quantity, price, trn_date)
VALUES (''$username', '$productname', '$quantity', '$price', '$trn_date')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input id="quantity_input" name="quantity" pattern="[0-9]*" value="1">
          
<?php $price=200; echo $price; ?>                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="button cart_button"></input>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to store the information that is related to the navigation of the page or Page Visit information in the database. (Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong as that is what your explanation suggests).

The easiest way to do this is to include a query on top of every PHP page, visited by user, which inserts the relevant information to the database table. This way you'll get to know the complete list of pages that the user has visited.

Hope this helps.